# How is params[:id] available to the create action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Rails and am practicing by writing the classic blog application.

```
def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.update(article_params)
  flash.notice = "Article '#{@article.title}' updated!"
  redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

How is `params[:id]` available to the `update` method? My `form_for` just passes in the `@article` object from:

```
def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

From looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object, the url that the form will POST to is `/articles/create`. It doesn't seem to have a query string, so `id` doesn't seem to be sent via GET. And from what I understand, `params[:articles]` is all that is being passed in via POST. So how is `params[:id]` available to the `update` action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`update` is a `PUT`, and the url constructed is `/articles/1`

`create` is a `POST`, and the url constructed is `/articles`

This is what really is in the doc.

So now you can see where the `id` param comes from in `update`, and yes there is no id for `create` :)

Comment: So when the form is submitted, it knows to do a `PUT` rather than a `POST` because the `@article` that was initially passed in had fields filled out?

Comment: No, the form helpers checks if the object is persisted (.persisted?) and builds the url accordingly

Comment: Ok, and it's able to build the url with an `id` because it uses the `id` of the page the form is on?

Comment: No it uses the to_param of the object

Answer (score 1):

It's go to update through rails router. Read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default). If you look into config/routes.rb of your application you will find something like this:

```
resources :articles
```

and if you run rake routes task inside you application it'll return something like:

```
     articles GET    /articles(.:format)               articles#index
              POST   /articles(.:format)               articles#create
  new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)           articles#new
 edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format)      articles#edit
      article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)           articles#show
              PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)           articles#update
              PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)           articles#update
              DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)           articles#destroy
```

so it's how RESTful resource are maps HTTP verbs. So when you create article there is no :id because obviously you will get it from DB auto increment counter. And when you update it, you already have id and route your request to /articles/:id with HTTP PUT request. And :id there is query param that will be available in controller action.

Answer (score 0):

```
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
```

is returning instance of article include the ID of the article and all the fields that are in the database.

then (i guess you have form) in parsing the instance and show all the fields in the model.

then when you press submit it pass all changes in hash into update method(PUT method in browser).

hope in answered your question.